# applicationDidEnterBackground & applicationWillResignActive are not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I am creating a simple application which perform some task on main thread. I am printing process in `NSLog` so I can understand that my process is running or not.

Now when I press home button without starting the process (Process will be start when I tap on a button) application enters in background and my both of methods `applicationDidEnterBackground` & `applicationWillResignActive` are being called.

But when I first tap on my button and process starts on main thread after that if I press home button none of these two method being called. So my application can't know that app entered in background or not.

Even after that when I again active the app it shows me a black screen with status bar only.

1. Why this is happening?
2. Why app not entering in background?
3. Why apple's methods not being called?
4. Is there a way to solve it?

**UPDATE** 
Here is my appdelegate class code

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

All methods have no implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your delegate class code on your project?

Comment: What does your process look like?

Comment: Always try to put some code???

Comment: @Dinesh I didn't write even a single line in my delegate class.

Comment: @waheeda both of my methods are not being called that is the problem as I mentioned :)

Comment: @AnilKothari if there is some code which can be put here surely I had done. The thing is my application is not entering in background properly. Second I am getting video frame using my app so that is a different scenario

Comment: The question is why app is not entering in background. Let me know for this what code you needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am creating a simple application which perform some task on main thread.

**Don't perform long-running operations on the main thread.**

The delegate callbacks happen on the main thread. If the main thread is busy, then the callbacks won't happen until you return to the "run loop".

When foregrounding your app, the OS actually displays a screenshot if available, falling back to the launch image (Default.png). The screenshot is taken after `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` returns, which allows you to customize what gets saved (you might want to do this for security reasons, or to hide UI elements which might not make sense to show when relaunching e.g. a countdown timer).

The black screen is probably because your app has no launch image. If your app takes more than about 10 seconds to enter the background (and it does, since the main thread is blocked), it gets killed. Except the debugger is attached and catches SIGKILL, so it's easy to miss unless you're watching Xcode.

Comment: I was searching the web to find out when the os will call applicationDidEnterBackground in case of heavy computations on the main thread for about 2 days and no luck, until I found this answer. Thanks man, you saved me. Your answer is very professional and clear. Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

there are some cases

if `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key set to true in your app's `Info.plist`, the applicationWillResignActive method is not called when the user hits the home button. and may b some thing other. check keys here [Apple keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) and see if something new you added to plist. and there is no other case that you say your delegate method not calling. it may also some time due to project in appropriate behavior. try cleaning your project and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

this is going to sound strange but for those it helps.  I had the same issue and cleaned my project and then it started working again.